Twilio - WhatsApp error 63018 "Rate limit exceeded for Channel"
Using Twilio API to send WhatsApp messages using Python.  Sending rate is about 1 message per second.  Have a confirmed business account with Meta/WhatsApp and the phone number is approved for 1,000 business-initiated messages per 24-hour period.
Trying to do some type of load test by sending messages to a single number - my number.  All is good for 50+ messages and then I get the above error.  Neiter the API rate limit nor the max messages per day are being exceeded.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
I have looked at the error code documentation and it does not seem to fit the situation.  I have tried Twilio web support but no response yet.

It may be that too many messages to one user also triggers rate limiting.

Can you add the code you run to send these messages? And does Twilio return the recipe IDs (MMxxxx) right away but the delivery is delayed to do you get an error when you sent the messages?

@IObert I receive a Message SID.  The Twilio log shows Message Created, Enqueued,, Dequeued and then the Failed status just over a second after the Created.

It sounds like you're running into a limitation of the WhatsApp Sender’s Throughput, which is not to be confused with the WhatsApp Messaging Limits. But I agree, the naming is confusing...

Note: A WhatsApp Sender’s Messaging Limits are not the same as a WhatsApp Sender’s Throughput, which is measured in Messages per Second (MPS). Default MPS for WhatsApp Senders is 10 MPS for Text and 1.5 MPS for Media.

Source
This rate can be increased up to the maximum of 50 MPS by request and pending approval upon review of the business's messaging requirements. If you require sending messages at high MPS for more than a few minutes, please contact the support team for guidance and best practices prior to your campaign. (more details)

I greatly appreciate your feedback.  I still don't understand why.  I have 1,000 business-initiated messages per 24 hours and I am at less than 10.  My sending rate when the error message appears is about 1 message per second, well below the 10 MPS limit.  It seems there must be something else.  We are just a few days from rolling this out for our annual event and I have lost all confidence.  Any suggestions?

I'm sorry you're under that kind of pressure. I'm afraid this would require support to look at your individual case.

I am also facing same @Bryan . Is it resolved for you?

Turns out I was receiving this error message while testing.  My test was to send many messages to myself, this triggered the error message.  Once it was placed into production, I was able to send to multiple addresses this error was never received again.
